# How do I as associate gradle tasks with keyboard commands in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

In IntelliJ IDEA it is possible to associate gradle tasks with keyboard shortcuts [1]. Is this possible in Eclipse and if so how do I do that?

[1] https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/associating-gradle-tasks-with-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse , Go to Windows->preference -"Search Keys". Once you opened the Keys settings, search "Run Gradle Tasks". Select it and give your preferred shortcut key in "Binding" field. I gave "Ctrl+Shift+C", since it was not used already.

Make sure you select the gradle tasks(I selected "Clean" tasks in the project(one time activity) and run the shortcut key.

Now when you are done coding changes, slect the Gradle task window (you tasks "Clean" should have been already selected)  and  run the Shortcut key.